# Retrieving data from a csv, and assigning the value at row x and column y to a variable. Py3.2, *homework*

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an assessment to do, and here's my code so far:

```
number1 = input("Number1? ")

number2 = input("Number2? ")

packages = csv.reader(open('lol.txt', newline='\n'), delimiter=',')
for PackName,PriceAdultString,PriceChildString in packages:
    n += 1
    PriceAdult = float(PriceAdultString)
    PriceChild = float(PriceChildString)
    print("%i. %17s - $%4.2d / $%4.2d" % (n, PackName, PriceAdult, PriceChild))

NameChoice = input("Which name would you like? Choose using a number: ")
```

The lol.txt used by csv.reader consists of the following:

```
herp,123,456    
derp,321,654    
hurr,213,546
```

Now, I need to be able to use NameChoice to retrieve a row from the file, and use the data within as name, number1, and number2, so for NameChoice == 1, name = herp, number1 = 123 and number 2 = 456, and the numbers must be a floating point number.

I'm having trouble figuring this out, and could use some guidance if that's possible.

Thanks all.

Before it's asked, I realised I forgot to mention: I have googled, and trawled through the Python guides, and my textbooks. I'm not entirely convinced I know what I'm looking for, though.

Run into a new problem:
I need to be able to take CSV text with '\n\n' instead of '\n', so the text is more like the following:

```
herp,123,456

derp,321,654

hurr,213,546
```

My (very slightly adjusted) version of the code Li-Aung used:

```
import csv
with open ("lol.txt",'rt', newline = '\n\n') as f:
    csv_r = csv.reader (f)
    entries = [ (name, float(p1), float(p2)) for name, p1, p2 in csv_r]

for index, entry in enumerate(entries):
    print ("%2i. %-10s %5.2f %5.2f" % (index, entry[0], entry[1], entry[2]))

choice = int(input("Choose a number: "))

print (entries[choice])
```

Which returns the exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python32/eh", line 2, in <module>
    with open ("lol.txt",'rt', newline = '\n\n') as f:
ValueError: illegal newline value:
```

Now, the debug is pretty clear - '\n\n' is not acceptable as a newline specifier, but I was wondering if there is a way around this?

Note: Screwed up the previous edit, the debug from the code with " newline = '\n'" would have been:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python32/eh", line 4, in <module>
    entries = [ (name, float(p1), float(p2)) for name, p1, p2 in csv_r]
  File "C:/Python32/eh", line 4, in <listcomp>
    entries = [ (name, float(p1), float(p2)) for name, p1, p2 in csv_r]
ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
```

Which is because it treated the blank space with 0 values between each useful row as a row, as it was told to do, and there was nothing in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the entire file to a list:

```
import csv
with open ("lol.txt",'rb') as f:
    csv_r = csv.reader (f)
    entries = [ (name, float(p1), float(p2)) for name, p1, p2 in csv_r]

for index, entry in enumerate(entries):
    print ("%2i. %-10s %5.2f %5.2f" % (index, entry[0], entry[1], entry[2]))

choice = int(raw_input("Choose a number: "))

print (entries[choice])
```

Output:

```
 0. herp       123.00 456.00
 1. derp       321.00 654.00
 2. hurr       213.00 546.00
Choose a number: 0
('herp', 123.0, 456.0)
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone,
I think I'm almost there, but I'm not going to close the question just yet until I've implemented everything and checked I've got it working.
Barring some screwup, it should be closed in 4 or 5 hours (It's 9pm and I need to go out for a half hour or more to clear my head). 
Thanks again.
I'll up-vote you all when I'm able.

Answer (score 2):

@mata has the right of it, but I feel the need to elaborate on their answer more than I can in a comment.

Since you need to refer back to your data instead of just printing it, it makes sense to have it stick around somehow. Once you reach that point, the biggest thing you need to worry about is what kind of data structure to use - if your chosen data structure is a close match to how you want to use the data, the code becomes quite simple.

So, your logic will look like:

1. Parse the data into some kind of data structure
2. Walk this data structure to print out the menu
3. Get the user input, and use it to select the right bit of data

Since the user input is a number representing how far down the file the data is, a `list` is an obvious choice. If you were using one of the existing fields as a lookup, a `dict` would serve you better.

If you do:

```
data = list(csv.reader(open('lol.txt', newline='\n'), delimiter=','))
```

, you can walk it to print the menu the same way you current use the file, except that *the data sticks around*, and using the number you get in is directly meaningful.

You might prefer to store the numbers as number types than strings; it would make good sense to, but figuring out how to adjust the code above to achieve it is left as an exercise for the reader. :-)

Answer (score 1):

you could for example store the input in a `list` instead of just printing it out.

after that it's trivial to get the right tuple from the list and assign it to your variables...

Answer (score 0):

with open ("lol.txt",'rt', newline = '\n\n') as f:

change it to '\n'

with open ("lol.txt",'rt', newline = '\n') as f: